# Dagger2 generated class is all of a sudden missing from Android Studio

Tags: android, build, gradle, dagger-2

I have been using Dagger2 in Android Studio for months now but today all of sudden it stopped working and is giving me the following error

```
 error: cannot find symbol
        return Dagger_Injector.builder()
               ^

symbol:   variable Dagger_Injector
  location: class Initializer
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Here is the code where it is failing

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {TestService.class, ServiceFactory.class})
public interface Injector {

    public final static class Initializer {

        public static Injector init(ApplicationLoader app, boolean bypassVerification) {
            return Dagger_Injector.builder()
                    .testService(new TestService())
                    .serviceFactory(new ServiceFactory(app))
                    .build();
        }

    }

    void inject(ApplicationLoader obj);
}
```

Here is my gradle info

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64
```

And here is the content of my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'                
        }

    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/androidTest')
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'

    // configure max heap size of the test JVM
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsonic-1.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:2.0.8'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    apt     'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be some change in Dagger 2 itself. I'm seeing the same problems although I haven't changed anything from yesterday. Unfortunately, Dagger 2 is still a snapshot, so it might change :/

Comment: Same problem here. I even tried to use the fixed 2.0 version of Dagger, but it's still failing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So it looks like for some reason there are no more underscores in names of generated component classes. Just look into yours `build/generated/source/apt` folder to see it really changed this way.

Fix it by replacing `Dagger_Injector` with `DaggerInjector` etc.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. They changed it in the release version. Although the documentation [http://google.github.io/dagger/](http://google.github.io/dagger/) still mentions the old way with `Dagger_` prefix. Javadoc of `Component` mentions `Dagger` prefix.

Comment: hmmmm ... quite strange, as here in this issue https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/58 - they seem to collectively have agreed on using the underscore. Anyway you are right. Removing the underscore does solve it.

Comment: They have released Dagger 2.0 (non-snapshot) a few hours ago. Some of the API has changed. http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/31ufbh/dagger_20_has_been_released/

Comment: I am not using underscores, and defining it correctly, yet still getting this error.

Comment: Any other solutions for this issue, I too can't see the folders under generated. clean and rebuild doesn't work as well :(

Comment: In my case, IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio cannot find the type, but ./gradlew  assemble succeeds.

Comment: @DerekS Yeah actually all I did is to "make project" in Android Studio. It will generate the class for you, but you need to make sure your dependency injection annotations are all placed correctly.

Comment: Nice that worked, for anyone else who's having the same issue I had to remove my DaggerClassName import before using "make project" otherwise it would continue to fail building off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

In My case I was using realm and due to apt mismatch I was not being able to get the autogenerated DaggerComponent.

I replaced

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
```

with

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.2"
```

and applied the plugin

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

in app-level gradle file