# Dagger2 does not generate "Dagger_" files

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Im using dagger 2 since a while, but today trying to compile got this error:

> Error:(13, 31) error: cannot find symbol class Dagger_GlobalComponent
>
> Error:(38, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable Dagger_GlobalComponent

So here is the code:

```
public class MyAppApplication extends Application {

private static GlobalComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = Dagger_GlobalComponent.builder()
            .busModule(new BusModule())
            .syncModule(new SyncModule())
            .serviceModule(new ServiceModule())
            .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
            .persistenceModule(new PersistenceModule(this))
            .build();
}}
```

And gradle dependencies:

```
...
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
...
```

Any solutions? Already tried to: Clean, Rebuild, Change dependecy versions, also deleting the Gradle cache and reinstalling Android Studio.

If it helps also got the same error with this sample projects:

https://github.com/gk5885/dagger-android-sample

https://github.com/mgrzechocinski/dagger2-example

Comment: square developers just removed the underscore, you can use it like this DaggerYourComponent after compile of course

Answer (score 36):

I was trying to follow the Dagger2 tutorial on tutsplus [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-on-android--cms-23345) and ran into the same issue when trying to use the underscore syntax (Dagger_ClassnameComponent).

As others have stated, the new Dagger APIs don't use that underscore syntax, but rather just use the syntax DaggerClassnameComponent. However, on attempting to use the new syntax in my simple app, the class DaggerClassnameComponent was not found. I believe it should be located in the app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/packagename/component folder.

At first, I didn't have any files generated under the above mentioned folder. However, **my solution was to clean and build the project,** and then I could use the Component class as expected.

Comment: +1 This worked for me when I thought the `apt` gradle plugin would have generated it. However it seems it needs to build once at least.

Comment: @halfjew22 - Thanks for the solution. pjco's info also helped me. Had to successfully build the project first before you can reference DaggerClassnameComponent, otherwise, it will not generate the generated/source/apt/ files

Answer (score 10):

[Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger#installation) has now been released, so you'll need to change your gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
provided 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like they removed the underscore from the generated stuff.  See [Dagger2 generated class is all of a sudden missing from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509014/dagger2-generated-class-is-all-of-a-sudden-missing-from-android-studio).